# using opendns, but why does dnsleak test show 5 opendns ip's?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vpn, dns, openvpn

Am using a vpn along with opendns, so there's no dns leaks. I use dnsleaktest to check, and it shows many opendns ip's.

Shouldn't it just show on dns ip being in use? I'm not sure if I have my dns configured correctly. The dns is being pushed from the server the vpn is located on, my tap adapter and wireless adapter (in windows 7 pc) are both set to obtain dns server address automatically.

Comment: OpenDNS using numerious servers to provide their service.  I am not sure what you concern is exactly.